# Use Ajax for a user registration form in WP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, ionic2

I have created a custom registration form with the additional field "Address". We are using the WP Rest API for the registration of a user.

The created function call Google Maps to get the geodata of the entered address. This function is also used for an Ionic App.

I would like to use this registration function for the WP site as well. So I created an html form.

Following you'll find the form with two input fields in order to keep the code compact.

```
<form>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['first_name'] ) : ''; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['last_name'] ) : ''; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['username'] ) : ''; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="address"><?php _e( 'Store address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['address'] ) ) ? 
        </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            </p>
</form>
```

And then I created an Ajax script, which should call the function from the url. However, the registration is not working.

Can you help me to fix the bug?

```
    (function( $ ){
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
       $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
      $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url: 'https://url/wp-json/wp-json/sow/v1/regist_user/',
           dataType : 'json',
           data: data,
           beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', JP_POST_EDITOR.nonce );
           },
 
           success: function(response) {
               alert( JP_POST_EDITOR.successMessage );
               $( "#results").append( JSON.stringify( response ) );
           },
           failure: function( response ) {
               alert( JP_POST_EDITOR.failureMessage );
           }
       });

});
    });
    })( jQuery );
```

Here is the function in my ionic app, which I try to rewrite for my website.

```
  createVendor(params, data) {
    var service = this;
    let url = service.appConfig.Shop_URL + "/wp-json/sow/v1/regist_user/";
    url = this.initUrl(url, params);
    let content = new URLSearchParams();
    for (var key in data) {
      if (data[key] && data[key] != null && data[key] != '') {
          content.set(key, data[key]);
      }
    }

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      service.http.post(url, content.toString(), { headers: headers }).catch(err => {
        reject('error');
        return Observable.throw(err);
      }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          if (data) {
          service.cachedData = data;
          resolve(service.cachedData);
        }
        else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: `data: data,` where is data defined?

Comment: oh well, I need to define the data before correct?

Comment: correct :) It can be achieved by reading all input fields with jQuery and then creating your desired data object with those values. Maybe there is an easier way but I have not used js/jQuery for too long so I can't help you here

Comment: like this? data: $('form').serialize(),

Comment: to my knowloedge, serialize generates a string, not an object. But as I said, I do not feel competent enough for further questions on js / jQuery

Comment: maybe I will try to use curl to post this request.